# how to apply Group By to this SQL Query

Tags: sql, pervasive-sql

I'm trying to make a list of inventory to be counted, provided the item has had a sale in the last 2 months:
I'm using Pervasive SQL and it's a BusinessVision table.
This query works, but I don't know how to aggregate to have one item displayed:

```
SELECT "INVENTORY"."CODE", "INVENTORY"."INV_DESCRIPTION", 
"INVENTORY"."BVSTKUOM", "INVENTORY"."INV_COMMITTED", 
 "INVENTORY"."ONHAND",
"SALES_HISTORY_HEADER"."IN_DATE"
FROM "INVENTORY" INNER JOIN "SALES_HISTORY_DETAIL" ON "SALES_HISTORY_DETAIL"."CODE" = "INVENTORY"."CODE" INNER JOIN "SALES_HISTORY_HEADER" ON "SALES_HISTORY_HEADER"."NUMBER" = "SALES_HISTORY_DETAIL"."NUMBER"
    where "INVENTORY"."PROD" like 'A6O%' AND "SALES_HISTORY_HEADER"."IN_DATE" > '20090731'
```

Ok. This query would give me repeated results of a part number, with different dates. I just want to have one occurrence for each part number, provided it as sold in the last 2 months.
For example:

```
A6001-O15P   HP 700-101-O White 15" Perf   yds        0.00000      915.00000   20090810 
A6001-O15P   HP 700-101-O White 15" Perf   yds        0.00000      915.00000   20090811 
A6001-O15P   HP 700-101-O White 15" Perf   yds        0.00000      915.00000   20090812
```

I would prefer simply have it like this:

```
A6001-O15P   HP 700-101-O White 15" Perf   yds        0.00000      915.00000
```

and on the next row the next product.
How can I do that?

EDITED PART AFTER SOME ANSWERS:
Thanks for the suggestion about DISTINCT.
I don't know why it repeats results yet. See (part of) the result of the query (not including "SALES_HISTORY_HEADER"."IN_DATE":

```
CODE           INV_DESCRIPTION                 BVSTKUOM   INV_COMMITTED   ONHAND    
--------------------------------------------------------- --------------- ----------
A6001-O15NP    HP 700-101-O White 15" NP       yds        0.00000         180.00000 
A6001-O15P     HP 700-101-O White 15" Perf     yds        0.00000         915.00000 
A6001-O15P     HP 700-101-O White 15" Perf     yds        0.00000         915.00000 
A6001-O15P     HP 700-101-O White 15" Perf     yds        0.00000         915.00000 
A6001-O15P     HP 700-101-O White 15" Perf     yds        0.00000         915.00000 
A6001-O15P     HP 700-101-O White 15" Perf     yds        0.00000         915.00000 
A6001-O15P     HP 700-101-O White 15" Perf     yds        0.00000         915.00000 
A6001-O15P     HP 700-101-O White 15" Perf     yds        0.00000         915.00000 
A6001-O15P     HP 700-101-O White 15" Perf     yds        0.00000         915.00000 
A6001-O15P     HP 700-101-O White 15" Perf     yds        0.00000         915.00000 
A6001-O15P     HP 700-101-O White 15" Perf     yds        0.00000         915.00000 
A6001-O15P     HP 700-101-O White 15" Perf     yds        0.00000         915.00000 
A6001-O15P     HP 700-101-O White 15" Perf     yds        0.00000         915.00000 
A6001-O15P     HP 700-101-O White 15" Perf     yds        0.00000         915.00000 
A6001-O15P     HP 700-101-O White 15" Perf     yds        0.00000         915.00000
```

And when using the GROUP BY, or DISTINCT I get these results:

```
CODE           INV_DESCRIPTION                 BVSTKUOM   INV_COMMITTED   ONHAND    
--------------------------------------------------------- --------------- ----------
A6001-O15NP    HP 700-101-O White 15" NP       yds        0.00000         50.00000  
A6001-O15NP    HP 700-101-O White 15" NP       yds        0.00000         180.00000 
A6001-O15P     HP 700-101-O White 15" Perf     yds        0.00000         0.00000   
A6001-O15P     HP 700-101-O White 15" Perf     yds        0.00000         915.00000
```

I would expect just 2 rows, the ones with 180 and 915.

Comment: When I saw the Pervasive tag, I thought "No... Don't let this be about BusinessVision"...

Comment: Could you tell me a little more about your attitude towards BusinessVision? I agree it is not so user friendly and they leave a lot of stuff missing so 3rd parties can fill the gap, which can be expensive solutions.

Comment: @Eduardo: I've worked with BV, v6 to v7.1  I believe it to be better than alternative Cdn accounting programs, if only because it's the kitchen sink (includes everything).  But the user interface and data model leaves a lot to be desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that the problem with duplicates was because I forgot to filter out warehouses. I should have added in the where clause this:

WHERE "INVENTORY"."WHSE" = '00'

This took care of the problem

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Pervasive SQL, but normally you have to group by all the columns you want grouped, in this case that's all the columns (except "SALES_HISTORY_HEADER"."IN_DATE", which isn't in your desired output)

```
SELECT "INVENTORY"."CODE", "INVENTORY"."INV_DESCRIPTION", 
"INVENTORY"."BVSTKUOM", "INVENTORY"."INV_COMMITTED", 
 "INVENTORY"."ONHAND"
FROM "INVENTORY" INNER JOIN "SALES_HISTORY_DETAIL" ON "SALES_HISTORY_DETAIL"."CODE" = "INVENTORY"."CODE" INNER JOIN "SALES_HISTORY_HEADER" ON "SALES_HISTORY_HEADER"."NUMBER" = "SALES_HISTORY_DETAIL"."NUMBER"
where "INVENTORY"."PROD" like 'A6O%' AND "SALES_HISTORY_HEADER"."IN_DATE" > '20090731'
group by "INVENTORY"."CODE", "INVENTORY"."INV_DESCRIPTION", 
"INVENTORY"."BVSTKUOM", "INVENTORY"."INV_COMMITTED", 
 "INVENTORY"."ONHAND"
```

Answer (score 1):

So the Pervasive Control Center (8.70.014.000) doesn't have an explain plan or anything that looks like profiling, so I can't speak beyond personal perception.  But to me, the GROUP BY feels a tad faster:

```
    SELECT t.code, 
           t.inv_description,
           t.bvstkuom,
           t.inv_committed,
           t.onhand,
           shh.in_date
      FROM "INVENTORY" t
INNER JOIN "SALES_HISTORY_DETAIL" shd ON shd.code = t.code
INNER JOIN "SALES_HISTORY_HEADER" shh ON shh.number = shd.number
  GROUP BY t.code, 
           t.inv_description,
           t.bvstkuom,
           t.inv_committed,
           t.onhand,
           shh.in_date
```

Mind that Pervasive requires you to include all columns that don't have aggregate functions performed.

Version using DISTINCT:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT t.code, 
           t.inv_description,
           t.bvstkuom,
           t.inv_committed,
           t.onhand,
           shh.in_date
      FROM "INVENTORY" t
INNER JOIN "SALES_HISTORY_DETAIL" shd ON shd.code = t.code
INNER JOIN "SALES_HISTORY_HEADER" shh ON shh.number = shd.number
```

What version of BV/Pervasive are you dealing with?  I can test against v6/2000i if need be.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. The version I have for pervasive is 8.70.14
The group by query works if I don't include the "SALES_HISTORY_HEADER"."IN_DATE"
in the select and group by, otherwise I get this error:
ODBC Error: SQLSTATE = 37000, Native error code = 0 
Syntax Error: SELECT "INVENTORY"."CODE", "INVENTORY"."INV_DESCRIPTION", 
"INVENTORY"."BVSTKUOM", 
"INVENTORY"."INV_COMMITTED",
"INVENTORY"."ONHAND"
"SALES_HISTORY_HEADER".<< ??? >>"IN_DATE"

FROM "INVENTORY"
INNER 

See about the comments on results for the other post.

Comment: Ah, so you've got a BV 7.0 install :)

Comment: I didn't have any problem with the group by when I was testing - try the one I provided.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't tried your example. Actually I did just follow your recommendation with my own verbose code. Yes it works. +1 for showing me that Pervasive accepts this convention of code abbreviation. Thanks. However I suspect I need to do another query on this query so I can get rid of the duplicates, yet.

Comment: @Eduardo: Yeah, I knew Pervasive supported table aliases.  But I was seeing the same thing in my data - the data field is automatically suspect for inflating rows grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're not looking for SELECT DISTINCT, which returns a single row if there are duplicates? If you exclude the IN_DATE from your SELECT, I think this is what you want.

```
SELECT DISTINCT "INVENTORY"."CODE", "INVENTORY"."INV_DESCRIPTION", 
"INVENTORY"."BVSTKUOM", "INVENTORY"."INV_COMMITTED", 
 "INVENTORY"."ONHAND"
FROM "INVENTORY" INNER JOIN "SALES_HISTORY_DETAIL" ON "SALES_HISTORY_DETAIL"."CODE" = "INVENTORY"."CODE" INNER JOIN "SALES_HISTORY_HEADER" ON "SALES_HISTORY_HEADER"."NUMBER" = "SALES_HISTORY_DETAIL"."NUMBER"
    where "INVENTORY"."PROD" like 'A6O%' AND "SALES_HISTORY_HEADER"."IN_DATE" > '20090731'
```